# Style proprety in JSX reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to implement on reactjs called Gallery which look like this on html:

```
<div class="grid-gallery" style="--grid-desktop:4; --grid-tablet:4; --grid-phone:4; 
    --grid-gap:var(--space-base); --grid-list-desktop:5; --grid-list-tablet:5; --grid-list-phone:5;">
    <div data-container="" class="column-item-preview">1</div>
    <div data-container="" class="column-item-preview">2</div>
    <div data-container="" class="column-item-preview">3</div>
    <div data-container="" class="column-item-preview">4</div>
    <div data-container="" class="column-item-preview">5</div>
    <div data-container="" class="column-item-preview">6</div>
    <div data-container="" class="column-item-preview">7</div>
    <div data-container="" class="column-item-preview">8</div>
</div>
```

And few changes are applied on the numbers of the css classes on styles. When I put this in the return of the component's function it's not working because of style parameter.

How can I "translate" this to JSX?

Comment: Read the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style, https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html

Answer (score -1):

Use className instead of class. So your code will look like-

Answer (score -1):

```
 <div className="grid-gallery" style={{-gridDesktop: 4, -gridTablet: 4, -gridPhone: 4, -gridGap: 'var(--space-base)', -gridListDesktop: 5, -gridListTablet: 5, -gridListPhone: 5}}>
        <div data-container className="column-item-preview">1</div>
        <div data-container className="column-item-preview">2</div>
        <div data-container className="column-item-preview">3</div>
        <div data-container className="column-item-preview">4</div>
        <div data-container className="column-item-preview">5</div>
        <div data-container className="column-item-preview">6</div>
        <div data-container className="column-item-preview">7</div>
        <div data-container className="column-item-preview">8</div>
      </div>
```

Use this syntax.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <div class="grid-gallery" style="--grid-desktop:4; --grid-tablet:4; --grid-phone:4; 
    --grid-gap:var(--space-base); --grid-list-desktop:5; --grid-list-tablet:5; --grid-list-phone:5;">
    <div data-container="" className="column-item-preview">1</div>
    <div data-container="" className="column-item-preview">2</div>
    <div data-container="" className="column-item-preview">3</div>
    <div data-container="" className="column-item-preview">4</div>
    <div data-container="" className="column-item-preview">5</div>
    <div data-container="" className="column-item-preview">6</div>
    <div data-container="" className="column-item-preview">7</div>
    <div data-container="" className="column-item-preview">8</div>
</div>
```

This should do the job